# SunOS acomp and ccfe Segmentation Fault

Tags: compiling, solaris, c++

I am trying to compile a simple hello world program in SunOS (5.5.1 Generic_103640-42 sun4u sparc SUNW,Ultra-5_10) ,the problem we are facing is when we try to compile a simple C++ file, we are observing a segmentation fault.Initially we were able to compile, nothing got updated in server I have cross checked, please find my observations..

```
$/apps/SUNWspro/bin/CC -C chandru.C
CC: Warning: Option -C passed to ld, if ld is invoked, ignored otherwise
CC: Fatal error in ccfe: Segmentation Fault (core dumped)
$ls -l /apps/SUNWspro/bin/CC
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root     other         15 Aug 23  1999 /apps/SUNWspro/bin/CC -> ../SC5.0/bin/CC
$/apps/SOLARIS/C++4.1/bin/CC -V chandru.C
CC: diagnostics generated from compilation of chandru.int.c:
cc: Fatal error in /apps/SUNWspro/bin/../SC5.0/bin/acomp
Status 139
CC: end of diagnostics from compilation of chandru.int.c:
$ls -l /apps/SOLARIS/C++4.1/bin/CC
-r-xr-xr-x   1 scmeadm  scme       44524 Jan 30  1998 /apps/SOLARIS/C++4.1/bin/CC
$cat chandru.C

#include "stdio.h"
int main()
{
        printf("Hello\n");
        return 0;
}
```

```
spe:/scmeadm> which CC
/apps/SOLARIS/C++4.1/bin/CC
spe:/usr/att/scmeadm> ldd /apps/SUNWspro/bin/CC
        libintl.so.1 =>  /usr/lib/libintl.so.1
        libc.so.1 =>     /usr/lib/libc.so.1
        libw.so.1 =>     /usr/lib/libw.so.1
        libdl.so.1 =>    /usr/lib/libdl.so.1
        /usr/platform/SUNW,Ultra-5_10/lib/libc_psr.so.1
spe:/scmeadm> ldd /apps/SOLARIS/C++4.1/bin/CC
ldd: /apps/SOLARIS/C++4.1/bin/CC: unsupported or unknown file type

After I cross checked with which CC ,again I complied with these steps 
#/apps/SUNWspro/bin/CC -C chandru.C
CC: Warning: Option -C passed to ld, if ld is invoked, ignored otherwise
CC: Fatal error in ccfe: Segmentation Fault (core dumped)
```

```
PATH=/now_scme/lbin:/apps/build/i1010/sun5.6/delta/i/prod/bin:/usr/ccs/bin:/bin:/usr/bin:/now_scme/bin2.1_Sun5.5:/now_scme/bin2.1_Hpux1020:/apps/SOLARIS/C++4.1/bin:/apps/SOLARIS/nmake3.2/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/oss/scmeadm/bin:.
CPLUSLIB=/apps/SOLARIS/C++4.1/lib
CC=/apps/SOLARIS/C++4.1/bin/CC
CPLUSINC=/apps/SOLARIS/C++4.1/include
```

Comment: Post the output of `env` and `ldd /apps/SUNWspro/bin/CC`.

Comment: Anything in `/var/adm/messages` that indicates memory or disk problems?

Comment: I have edited my question and pasted the ldd /apps/SUNWspro/bin/CC and /var/adm/messages I cross checked but no helpful messages...Thanks Mark and Andrew

Comment: I'm curious why you're getting: "ldd: /apps/SOLARIS/C++4.1/bin/CC: unsupported or unknown file type"

Can you issue a `file` on it as well?  I'm also curious if you have a space issue somewhere.  Try checking `df -k`

Comment: CC is probably a shell script.

Comment: Yes Mark it is shell script  (file /apps/SOLARIS/C++4.1/bin/CC
/apps/SOLARIS/C++4.1/bin/CC:    executable shell script) and @sleepy I have cross checked there is no space issues.